# Electron knex sqlite handling

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron, knex.js

I have some problem with Electron app, responding wiht knexjs and sqlite. 
I use knex and sqlite db file on node script, which is also responsible for electron bootstraping. 
When i run app from "electron" command, from console everything is ok, app works and db is ok. But when i packaged app with electron-packager app crashes on start (without any error). When i remove part in knex handling responsible for connection with sqlite file app works...

knex bootstraping looks like that:

```
let knex = require("knex")({
  client: "sqlite3",
  connection: {
    //when i comment this line app does not crash
    filename: path.join(app.getPath('userData'), 'database.sqlite') 
  }
});
```

Do you have any ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: i am also facing same issue

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?